# What is the Correct way of using Layers in Web Application

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, web-application-design

We have web application designed using Spring + Hibernate. Following are the layers in our application.

```
    JSP
     |
Controllers
     |
   Facade
     |
   Service
     |
    DAO
```

While going through the code I saw some **Service** classes uses the other **DAO** classes. Is this the correct approach? I would like to know what is the **correct way** of using layers. Should facade layers directly use objects of service layers or they should go through the other facade object? Same with service layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach for web application is

```
     JSP
      |
  Controllers
      |
   Manager
      |
   Service
      |
     DAO
```

Where

JSP : View part

Controllers : Handling the incoming requests and returns the response and proper view definitions

Manager : This will be inject into Controllers, this is logical/functional unit. One manager can serve the multiple controllers

Service : This is service layer and will be invoked by Managers only, hence this will be inject into Managers class

DAO : Data access objects and this will inject into service layer

This is most common trends now a day all web application is following.

Comment: So lets say I have `UserService` which require data related to bookmarks which is served by `BookmarkService/BookmarkDao`, then should `UserService` use `BookmarkService` or `BookmarkDao`??

Comment: You should use the BookmarkService and not UserService. In layerd architecture logic should be contains in the respective service only. Hence, UserService for user related information and BookmarkService for bookmark related information.

Comment: So that means calls to the **BookmarkService** and **UserService** should be made from **Manager layer** and two services(bookmark and user) should remain separate.

Comment: @code13 : atleast you should give some upvote while accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference link for [j2ee design pattern](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/), [different layers](http://techighost.com/list-all-j2ee-design-patterns/). [Another reference link to understand the concept](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/SessionFacade.htm).